# How do I save rendered DOM elements to a pdf

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm working on a part of a larger project. And this specific part is suppose to download parts of a websites content into pdf format. We are not married to the idea of it being a pdf format but there's a couple libraries that support this, so we went with it.

This is my code for saving some web contents to pdf:

```
const options = {
  margin: 0.3,
  filename: 'filename.pdf',
  image: { 
    type: 'jpeg', 
    quality: 0.98 
  },
  html2canvas: { 
    scale: 4 
  },
  jsPDF: { 
    unit: 'in', 
    format: 'a4', 
    orientation: 'portrait' 
  }
}


var objstr1 = document.getElementById('example1').outerHTML;
var objstr1 = document.getElementsByTagName('example2')[0].innerHTML;


var strr = '<html><head><title>Testing</title>';   
strr += '</head><body>';
strr += '<div style="border:0.1rem solid #ccc!important;padding:0.5rem 1.5rem 0.5rem 1.5rem;margin-top:1.5rem">'+example1+'</div>';
strr += '<div style="border:0.1rem solid #ccc!important;padding:0.5rem 1.5rem 0.5rem 1.5rem;margin-top:1.5rem">'+example2
+'</div>';
strr += '</body></html>';

$('#download_button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var element = document.getElementById('stuff
');
  //html2pdf().from(element).set(options).save();
  //html2pdf(element);
  html2pdf().from(strr).set(options).save();
});
```

In terms of the actual download it works great. Even though I got this from an example online and modified it a little to suit my tastes. For reference when I try to save a page that static it will save everything on that page no problem. My issue comes when something is rendered in the DOM. For example
example1 looks like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrn4T.png) when nothing is loaded and it looks like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpe1u.png). Now when I go to save the page only the headers (picture 1) is being saved and not the table it self.

What I tried so far was to save the whole page & Save only those specific elements.

I'm starting to get really attached to this script because its so close to perfect in terms of the functionality I want. Any help would be huge deal thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the complete DOM you're working with.  It sounds like maybe the content that's not being rendered to the PDF isn't actually a child element.  it could be a sibling or parent element with CSS making it look like a child.